# ¿ Quisiera ver si hay algo mal en este código de prueba para el uso de API de google maps?

Tags: javascript, html

He probado este código debido a que requiero el uso de las API para un proyecto de pagina web y no consigo saber que es lo que falla para que no me muestre el mapa en mi página (aun no he activado la facturación de las API y quiero saber si ese es el motivo de que no lo muestre o es otro factor el que lo esta afectando)
agradecería su pronta colaboración...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>prueba</title>
    <style>

    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
        #map{
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id ="map"></div>

<script>
alert("prueba");
    function initMap(){
      var location = {lat: -25.363, log: 131.044};
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsById("map"),{
        zoom: 4,
        center: location
      });
    }
</script>
<script> async defer src ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="my key"&callback=initMap"</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar tienes un error al incluir GoogleMaps, el cierre de la etiqueta script está mal colocado:

```
<script> async defer src ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&callback=initMap"</script>
```

Debe ser

```
<script async defer src ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Y este debe aparecer antes de que llames a la función `initMap()` en el código.

Y luego debes llamar a la función `initMap()` para cargar el mapa, por ejemplo puedes llamarla en el evento `onload` de la etiqueta body o de la página.

Comment: ya corregí lo que me dijiste pero me podrías explicar mejo la parte de que aparezca antes de la función initMap() ?

Comment: Quiere decir que el script de llamada a maps.googleapis.com debe aparecer en tu código por encima de del script donde defines la función initMap, por ejemplo pon el primero en el head. Sino puede producir errores del tipo 'googlemaps no está definido'.

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsById("map"),{
    zoom: 4,
    center: location
});
```

aqui hay un error de sintaxis, escribiste getElementsById en plural, la manera correcta es getElementById...
elements es para cuando seleccionas varios elementos por nombre de etiqueta